# Getting parent route in EmberJS

Tags: ember.js

I'm making a reusable (sort of polymorphic) comments widget. I want a button that enables me to go back to the parent route (e.g., if I'm at /blog_posts/1/comments, I want the button to take me back to /blog_posts/1).

I'm currently using `transitionToRoute('blog_post')`, but this won't work in the long run because I want this code to generically run with any model (i.e. it won't know anything about the route's name, so I can't call 'blog_post'). I guess I'm looking for either something like Rails' `url_for`, or a way of saying `router.get('parent_route')` (or `controller.get('parent_route')`).

Any pointers or ideas? Thanks.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

**This was answered in the year 2013 for ember v0.9.8 or something, the framework has come a long way since then. I think there might be a much better solution with the current version of the framework. Since, I'm not in touch with Ember, can't really update this answer!**

Inspired from a private function in the source code, Add the following method to the Routes which returns the name of the `parentRoute`

```
Ember.Route.reopen({
  getParentRoute: function(){
    var route = this;
    var handlerInfos = route.router.router.currentHandlerInfos;
    var parent, current;

    for (var i=0, l=handlerInfos.length; i<l; i++) {
      current = handlerInfos[i].handler;
      if((current.routeName == route.routeName)||(current.routeName.match(/./) && current.routeName.split('.')[1] == route.routeName )){
        return parent.routeName;
      }
      parent = current;
    }
  }
})
```

Use inside routes as follows

```
App.SomeRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
  events: {
    goBack: function(){
      this.transitionTo(this.getParentRoute());
    }
  }
})
```

Handlebars

```
<script type="text/x-handlebars" data-template-name="some">
  <a href="#" {{action goBack}}>Back</a>
</script>
```

For the actual code, open [this](https://raw.github.com/emberjs/ember.js/release-builds/ember-1.0.0-rc.2.js) and do a CTRL+F for  `function parentRoute`

Comment: Great answer - thank you. I've implemented this and it works a treat!

Comment: Note that you cannot use this to get the parent route of a route that is currently being transitioned to (for example when the page is being loaded) because currentHandlerInfos might not be set. I tried to use this in a route handler base class to get the parent's model without knowing its name, unfortunately page load is too soon to do so.

Comment: So this is a good way to get the parent route name of the CURRENT route, and not of the route object from which the method is called. That's because you're getting the routes' hierarchy through the `router`.

Comment: @Huafu This was answered when the framework was not as mature as it is right now. So I really suggest you to go through the latest guides so that you can find good leads related to best practices for implementing the same functionality.

Comment: you can also build upon what c4p answered, add the functionality on the Ember.Route class itself so that it auto generates the goBack method dynamically during initialization.

Comment: We started using this guy in our code, but I found unit testing it very difficult due to all the dependencies.

I ended up using this (which at least works for simple cases):

`return route.routeName.split('.').slice(0, -1).join('.');`

Does anything where this wouldn't work?

Comment: Hey Matt, look at my previous comment on this thread about how this answer was answered for ember-pre version & there might be better solutions with the current version of ember

Answer (score 6):

You can use a generic `{{action }}` in your template but have the specifics of the "go back" implemented in the router.  This works because Ember [bubbles up](http://emberjs.com/guides/templates/actions/#toc_target-bubbling) the `goBack` event first to the controller, then the current route, then the parent route, etc, until an action handler is found.  In this case, there is no matching action on the controller, so it is handled by the current route.  This keeps your template/view/controller agnostic to the specifics, but when you are hooking up the widget you can specify how the "go back" should be handled.

In the example the same button causes the route to change to different routes depending on which route is the current route:

- in route `/posts` the back button transitions to `/`
- in route `/posts/new` the back button transitions to `/posts`

[JSBin example](http://jsbin.com/emakuh/1/edit)

Javascript:

```
App = Ember.Application.create({});

App.Router.map(function() {
  this.resource('posts', function() {
    this.route('new');
  });
});

App.PostsRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
  events: {
    goBack: function(){
      this.transitionTo('index'); 
    }
  }
});

App.PostsNewRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
  events: {
    goBack: function(){
      this.transitionTo('posts'); 
    }
  }
});
```

Template:

```
<script type="text/x-handlebars" data-template-name="index">
  <h2>Index Content:</h2>
  {{#linkTo posts}}Posts{{/linkTo}}
  {{outlet}}
</script>

  <script type="text/x-handlebars" data-template-name="posts">
    <h2>Posts</h2>
    <button {{action goBack}}>Go back</button>
    {{#linkTo posts.new}}New{{/linkTo}}
    {{outlet}}
  </script>

  <script type="text/x-handlebars" data-template-name="posts/new">
    <h2>Posts/New</h2>
  </script>
```

Comment: Great answer - thanks! I've marked @Unspecified's as accepted because it will involve less setup for each new route I add - but this would have been a perfectly good implementation, so thanks :)

Comment: I think this can be implemented on Ember.Route class itself, which dynamically adds goBack method during route initialization. This is much cleaner too.

Answer (score 3):

Based on Mudasi Ali's lead and reviewing the Ember v1.5 source I use the following:

Coffeescript (use coffeescript.org to transpile if you want JS/ES):

```
Ember.Route.reopen
  parentRoute: Em.computed ->
    r = @router.router
    if r.currentTransition
      handlerInfos = r.currentTransition.state.handlerInfos
    else
       handlerInfos = r.state.handlerInfos

    handlerInfos = this.router.router.state.handlerInfos
    return unless handlerInfos

    parent = @
    for info in handlerInfos
      break if info.handler == @
      parent = info.handler
    parent

  parentRouteName: Em.computed.alias('parentRoute.routeName')

  parentController: ->
    @controllerFor @get('parentRouteName')

  parentModel: ->
    @modelFor @get('parentRouteName')
```

The above provides the properties `parentRoute` and `parentRouteName`, on all your routes and two handy functions `parentController()` and `parentModel()` which return the parent controller and model respectively which can be useful for many situations, especially if you represent editing a resource as a nested route.

You can also define some actions to use in your views/controllers etc for cancel/back handling as follows:

```
Ember.Route.reopen
  actions:
    goBack: ->
      @transitionTo @get('parentRouteName')
```

If you have a deep routing hierarchy and wanted to say skip an intermediate route, you just need to override goBack as follows:

```
App.SomeIntermediateRouteToSkipOnBack = Em.Route.extend
  actions:
    goBack: ->
      # skip the immediate parent and use the grandparent route
      @transitionTo @get('parentRoute.parentRouteName)
```

Answer (score 3):

**Updated for Ember 2.6**
in file `app/initializers/parent_route.js`

```
import Ember from 'ember';

var alreadyRun = false;

export default {
  name: 'parent-route',
  initialize: function() {
    if (alreadyRun) {
      return;
    } else {
      alreadyRun = true;
    }
    Ember.Route.reopen({
      parentRoute: Ember.computed(function() {
        let handlerInfos, i, info, len, parent, r;
        r = this.router.router;
        if (r.activeTransition) {
          handlerInfos = r.activeTransition.state.handlerInfos;
        } else {
          handlerInfos = r.state.handlerInfos;
        }
        if (!handlerInfos) {
          return;
        }
        parent = this;
        for (i = 0, len = handlerInfos.length; i < len; i++) {
          info = handlerInfos[i];
          if (info.handler === this) {
            break;
          }
          parent = info.handler;
        }
        return parent;
      }),
      parentRouteName: Ember.computed.alias('parentRoute.routeName'),

      parentController: Ember.computed(function() {
        return this.controllerFor(this.get('parentRouteName'));
      }),

      parentModel: Ember.computed(function() {
        return this.modelFor(this.get('parentRouteName'));
      })
    });

  }
};
```

In your routes you can access the parentcontroller like `this.get('parentController')` and the model like `this.get('parentModel')`